# Check if specific interrupt is enabled ( IPI )

Tags: assembly, intel, interrupt, lauterbach

I've read that EFLAGS has IF where it can store if interrupts are generally enabled, but i need to know if IPI ( inter-process interrupt ) is enabled.

I only have physical access to the CPU registers and data via Lauterbach debugger, i cannot access kernel or stuff like that.

Comment: You'd have to check the local APIC configuration. These are memory mapped registers so don't exist as part of the normal CPU register set. Also note that IPIs can use any interrupt vector so you'd have to check to see any interrupt is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term IPI designates a *category* of interrupts, specifically: [NMI](https://wiki.osdev.org/Non_Maskable_Interrupt), [SMI](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Management_Mode), SIPI, INIT and Fixed interrupts.
Of these, the NMI, SMI, SIPI and INIT cannot be masked without disabling the LAPIC globally.

---

The [NMI (Non-maskable Interrupt)](https://wiki.osdev.org/Non_Maskable_Interrupt) was designed to be non-maskable from the beginning, as the name implies.
There is a hack to mask it: setting the bit7 of port 70h.
However, this is a hardware trick, it ties the #NMI (today it is the LINT1 but this is configurable) high.
The IPIs are sent through a software message so this trick won't work.

The [SMI (System Management Interrupt)](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Management_Mode) is used to enter the SMM (see previous link), a mode designed to be as trasparent to the software as possible.
It is not maskable, for what the software is concerned, it doesn't exist.

The [INIT and SIPI (Startup-IPI)](https://wiki.osdev.org/Symmetric_Multiprocessing#Initialisation_of_an_old_SMP_system)<sup>1</sup> interrupts are used to reset and wake up a CPU.
They cannot be masked by design (the BIOS usually put the APs, Application Processors, to sleep with a `cli / hlt` sequence).

The Fixed interrupts can be masked with the `IF` flag or when a higher priority fixed interrupt ISR is executing (just like the legacy IRQs with the PIC).

---

It's possible to mask only the Fixed interrupts, something that may actually corresponds to the common understanding of the term IPI, by *soft* disabling the APIC.
This can be done by clearing bit8 of the *Spurious Interrupt Vector Register* at offset 0f0h from the LAPIC base (the LAPIC base is set in the `IA32_APIC_BASE` MSR, its address is 1bh).
Of course, clearing `IF` will also do.

Alternatively it's possible to disable the LAPIC entirely (it won't respond to *any* IPI) by clearing bit11 of the `IA32_APIC_BASE` MSR.

---

To check if the IPIs are enable you have to check the `IF` flag, the *Spurious Interrupt Vector Register* and the `IA32_APIC_BASE` MSR.

Comment: Hi, thanks; what are Fixed interrupts? Is there a definition?

Comment: @firo Fixed interrupts are IPIs with a specific vector number. They cause the CPU to execute the interrupt handler corresponding to the given vector. E.g. it's possible to send an IPI with a fixed interrupt with vector 0x40 to simulate an `int 40h` on the target processors.

Comment: @firo I've wrote something not true in the comment above. Fixed interrupts don't go true the "interrupt table", they make the CPU execute code from a specific, fixed, address. Hence the name.